# Raycast not working in Update() Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, transform, raycasting

I am making a game where an object follows my finger. But I do not want the object to jump to my finger if I tap anywhere on the screen. I am using a raycast to do this. It works perfectly except if I move my finger too fast the object freezes.

My theory is that because of it being in `Update()` that once I move my finger off the object it detects that I can no longer drag it. I have no idea how to fix this.

```C#
public GameObject Bigball;
public GameObject Smallball;

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update ()
{ 
    // lets ball follow finger
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector3 fingerPos = touch.position;
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(fingerPos);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && (hit.collider.tag == "ball"))
        {
            Smallball.SetActive(false);
            Bigball.SetActive(true);
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3((Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position)).x,
               (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position)).y, 0);
            Bigball.transform.position = pos;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Bigball.SetActive(false);
        Smallball.SetActive(true);
        Smallball.transform.position = new Vector3(Bigball.transform.position.x, Bigball.transform.position.y, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use ui drag but maybe just adding speed to the rigidbody helps.

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to only Raycast once when the finger touches the screen. If that Raycast finds an object to drag, simply store that object and move it to follow the finger every Update(), as long as the finger continues to touch the screen.

Once the finger is released, just forget about the object until the next touch finds a new object to drag.

An alternative would be to use no Raycasts at all but build on IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler and IEndDragHandler, as Bijan already mentioned.